# I used Update.callback_query after which i used Update.message in same function its not working

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

**update.callback_query.from_user** Inside the same function I used
**update.message.text**
where i tried to get message from user **update.message.text** is not working  giving me **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**
how can i use two update in same function

Answer (score 1):

To be exact you can find the `message` object (or/and the `text`) of a `callback_query` at `update.callback_query.message.text`.

Or for convenience you can always use `update.effective_chat`, `update.effective_message` and `update.effective_user` to access the `chat`, `message` and `from_user` objects wherever they are in (no matter it's a normal message, a `callback_query`, an `inline_query` etc.)